# What does the green dotted vertical line represent in the flame chart on the timeline panel?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

The blue dotted line around 475ms represents the `DOMContentLoaded` event. The red dotted line around 760ms represents the `load` event. But when I hover over the green dotted line it just says `Frame at 499ms`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the first paint. The hover area to trigger the tooltip is incredibly small and towards the top of the bulk at the top.

Answer (score 1):

- Green = first paint
- Blue = DOMContentLoaded
- Red = load